# HTML5 Iframe: Block remote requests

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

I am loading HTML content into an iframe using the srcdoc property. The iframe is a sandboxed iframe with no permissions given, so all Javascript in the iframe is blocked. However, remote requests (such as for CSS, images etc.) will still be triggered inside the iframe.

Is there any possible way to tell the iframe to only load what I give it in the srcdoc property and not make any additional requests?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The basics

Presumably no because sandboxing the iframe is meant to avoid sharing sensitive data between your main document and your iframe's document or limiting potentially disruptive behavior.

The iframe is still functionally a browser window and will act like such, loading all external resources that are declared in it, with the only difference that it displays within another document rather than another window.

If the code present inside `srcdoc` has calls to remote resources, then the browser is doing exactly what you are telling it to do by loading them.

If you don't want these resources to be loaded, you will have to edit them out of the `srcdoc` code.

### Actually, a possible solution

That being said, there might exist a way to block the loading of resources by using a `Content Security Policy` from within the iframe's document using a `meta` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none';">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none';">
```

I did try this under *Firefox 39.0.3* but it didn't work, likely because of the following:

[Bug 663570 - Implement Content Security Policy via  tag](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663570)

Regardless, for more information, see:

- [CSP (Content Security Policy) on the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP)
- [Content Security Policy Reference](http://content-security-policy.com/)

Comment: I only need this to work in Chrome (since this is for a desktop app using NW.js), so I'll definitely be looking into this.

Comment: I tried the CSP solution, but it still had a few rough edges (at that point in time - I'm sure the implementation is much better now), but eventually I settled for rewriting the page being served, and sanitizing the HTML. Probably not the solution you were looking for. Sorry.

Comment: You could load into a textarea inside the iframe, this will display the raw html and not call any remote requests, then give the user the option to remove the textarea to fully display.