# Is there a way to prevent an iframe from making any HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, html, sandbox

I have a peculiar use-case where I want to prevent an iframe from communicating.

1. Parent page is of xyz.com/index.html
2. Frame source is abc.com/widget.html

Once loaded, xyz.com/index.html communicates some information to the iframe. Iframe uses that data to construct a personalized UI.

Is there a way I can ensure that the iframe is not sending anything back to any server?

sandbox attributes cannot be used as they don't prevent usual get requests.

Is there anything which can be done here?

Comment: how is the iframe supposed to load if it can't make requests? even if you could stop xhr the page could still send data to the server by requesting an image or something else. what you want is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Iframe: Block remote requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903585/html5-iframe-block-remote-requests)

Comment: Consider simply loading the data with Ajax for instance, and pasting the outcome in a dom element on the "parent" page

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy ?